# Class member function pointer - Pointers to members have different representations; cannot cast between them

Tags: c++, function-pointers

I have the following data type to provide function pointers to class members with a specific prototype:

```
template<typename T> using FooHandler = bool(T::*)(BaseClass*, bool);
```

I would like to use this to reference the following member function:

```
bool ClassName::MethodName(DerivedClass* msg, bool byRef)
```

where DerivedClass is a class that derives from the abstract BaseClass.  However, this gives the compilation error "Pointers to members have different representations; cannot cast between them".

My intended usage is to be able to have the following expression in a generic routine:

```
BaseClass* classInstance = container[index];
FooHandler<BaseClass> handler = classInstance->inputHandler;
bool result = (classInstance->*handler)(data, true);
```

The easy fix is to change the prototype of the member function to:

```
bool ClassName::MethodName(BaseClass* msg, bool byRef)
```

but this means I will have to cast msg back to DerivedClass in the method implementation which is not elegant.  Are there any standard ways around this?

Comment: There's not much getting around that issue, since someone could always pass a pointer which does not point at a `DerivedClass` to a `FooHandler`, so you need to check whether it's a `DerivedClass` one way or another.

Answer (score 0):

You have to make the cast yourself in that case. If you don't want to do that cast everywhere, you can use a pointer to free function instead of a pointer to member function. That way, you can use a lambda with no capture:

```
template<typename T>
using FooHandler = bool(*)(T*, BaseClass*, bool);

// later on...

FooHandler<BaseClass> foo = [](BaseClass* c, BaseClass* p, bool b) {
    return c->inputHandler(static_cast<Derived*>(p), b);
};

foo(baseClass, derived, true); // call to the function.
```

Of course, you could also use `std::function`:

```
using FooHandler = std::function<bool(BaseClass*, bool)>;

// later on...

SomeClass c;

//                v--- captures c into the lambda
FooHandler foo = [c](BaseClass* p, bool b) {
    return c->someFunction(p, b);
};
```

In both way, you must do the cast. However, that cast is not longer in the `SomeClass` code, but in the lambda and the handler logic, so your classes stay with a nice stile, and the polymorphism and class hierarchy handling is now inside the handler logic.